# PHP Error: Constants get undefined after including them

Tags: php

Ok heres the problem. I defined a few constants to store in my database information.

Example -
FileName: **config.php**

```
<?php
//Define Database Constants

defined("DB_SERVER")   ? NULL : define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
defined("DB_NAME")     ? NULL : define("DB_NAME", "test");
defined("DB_USER")     ? NULL : define("DB_USER", "root");
defined("DB_PASSWORD") ? NULL : define("DB_PASSWORD", "password");

?>
```

I've included this in another file called **database.php** :

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");

class MySQLDatabase {
private $connection;

function __construct(){
    $this->open_connection();
}

public function open_connection(){
    $this->connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$this->connection){
        die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
    } else {
        $db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
        if(!$db_select){
            die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
        }
    }
}

}

$database = new MySQLDatabase();

?>
```

Here's the problem, whenever I include 'database.php' on another page, theres an error stating that I have undefined constants. Of course the database connection doesnt work either. Now, if I define these constants inside of 'database.php' instead of doing it on a different file, this works.

Is there a reason why this is happening?

Comment: I used your code in both ways(defining constants within same file as well as defining it in another file and including it) and its working correctly in both the cases here

Comment: Hmmm, then maybe something's wrong with my server? IDK maybe its something I need to change in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Defines a named constant at runtime that why is not call in the class.

if you are using like this , please make the variable as global.